# detect screen density using javascript on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, image-resizing

I was wondering if it is possible to detect the screen density from a web page by using javascript and/or some sort of server checking based on http headers on PHP. My goal is to check if the user is accessing the site from a tablet, phone or computer to adjust some button sizes - imagens on a html5 canvas. Exact pixel values may lead to buttons too small or too big depending on the screen density...

Comment: This is really a job for media queries.  You're looking for the "device pixel ratio", but other than that there's really no way to be sure of the actual physical geometry of a client device.

Comment: As an alternative to that, you could just check whether it's a tablet, cell phone or a regular lap/desk top browser by checking the user agent. Pretty much every mobile device nowadays has a similar pixel density, so most people I know don't check for screen resolution in such a precise way as you are asking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think most mobile browsers support `window.devicePixelRatio`.

Answer (score 1):

Most [browsers support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=devicepixelratio) `devicepixelratio` with the exception of Internet Explorer versions 8 through 10. Thankfully as of January 12th 2016 all those versions have been [officially deprecated](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support) and will no longer be supported by Microsoft with security updates or technical support.